# How do i write this second relationship to the same model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have two models, User and Community. A user can belong to many communities while a community can have many users. I have implemented many-to-many relationship for this in both models and then created a pivot table communities_users. In Community Model, i have the users(members) relationship defined:

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'communities_users', 'community_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

In User model, i have communities relationship defined as:

```
 public function communities(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Community', 'communities_users', 'user_id', 'community_id');
    }
```

I am able to call these relationships fine. No problems.
However, i need to add an admin_id on my communities table, representing the user that created the community (pointing to the same User model). I know this will be a belongsTo relationship in Community model and a hasMany relationship in User. I have added an admin_id column to my communities table. In my Community model, i have added my admin model like so;

```
public function admin(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'admin_id');
    }
```

If i try returning this, the app keeps breaking with a 500 Internal server error. How can i correct this and get it to return the user object that created the community?

Comment: What is the 500 error you're getting? What code is triggering this 500 error? You've got the correct idea; defining `public function admin()`, which is a `belongsTo()` (`Community` belongs to a single `Admin`, which is a `User`), and you'd set the FK as `admin_id` so Laravel doesn't try to use `user_id` (since it guesses at which column connects the 2 models).

Comment: Returning the admin relationship in the protected $with array of the community model returns the 500 error.

Comment: Once again, what is the error? Everything looks like it's correctly defined. Please enable debugging and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77152349/edit) to include the full code and the error it is triggering. A HTTP 500 Error can have _many_ causes, and unless you include the specific error message and associated lines of code that triggers it, we can't help you further.

Comment: @Tim, the error on the console each time i add that relationship to the $with array is just this:     `GET http://localhost:8000/api/get_communities net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)`. The Network Response tab isn't any helpful as it is only showing `Failed to load response data`.

Comment: Check your server logs. Anytime an HTTP 500 error is triggered, it should be logged to `storage/logs/laravel.log`. The Network tab should show more data if you have it open when the error is triggered.

Comment: @Tim, thanks. It is showing as a memory error in log. Something like this `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 528384 bytes)`. I am returning the communities relationship in user model, if i remove that, it works fine without any errors. However, i want the communities returned in user model, I have tried to eager-load the `admin` relationship in my controller and it works well also.

Comment: So the good news is that your relationship is working, but the bad news is that it's likely causing an infinite loop of some kind, or the data you're trying to load is too big. Be careful with `protected $withs`; if you do `['model.relationship']` in one model, then `['model.inverse']` in another model, Laravel will try to recursively load the relationship until it runs out of memory. You're probably better off doing `Model::with(...)->get()` to avoid this, unless you know for sure they you don't have any circular relationships.

Comment: @Tim, this exactly is the issue, infinite loop. I have used `Model::with()->get()` to load the relationship. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The **second parameter** that the belongsTo method takes is **foreign_key**!

in Community model:

```
public function admin(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); //Laravel considers 'id' by default
    }
```

in User model:

```
public function  adminOfCommunities(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Community', 'admin_id');
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think let's complete this database together from scratch

Your database as I understand it is as follows (part of it of course)

[image]

!! But if I don't understand, changing the relationship will solve the problem

Step 1:
In user migration, use ForeignId to define community_id

```
.
.
.
$table->foreignId('community_id')->constrained();
.
.
.
```

Step 2:
Use has Many and belongs_To in your model

Model User

```
public function communities(){
    return $this->hasMany(App\Community::class, 'community_id', 'id');
}
```

Model Community

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'community_id', 'id');
}
```

You can do the same for the admin model

!! If I didn't understand correctly, you can change the above connections, but the general work is the same as above

Comment: Thank you @Sina. However, there is no admin model. The admin_id references the User model. The idea is that a community has many users as members, but have just one admin(the creator). The users relationship with the community works fine, but where the error is happening is when i write the admin relationship for the creator of the community.